# Prove orthogonality of x and y

Tags: algebra-precalculus

if ||x + y|| = ||x - y|| then x and y must be orthogonal

Comment: Where do $x$ and $y$ lives? Finite dimensional euclidean space? Hilbert space? Some background is needed.

Comment: $\|x+y\|=\|x-y\|\implies \|x+y\|^2=\|x-y\|^2 \implies \langle x+y,x+y \rangle = \langle x-y,x-y \rangle$. Expand everything out and it should be clear.

Answer (score 2):

From $$\|x+y\|^2=\|x-y\|^2$$ we get $$\|x\|^2+2\langle x,y \rangle +\|y\|^2=\|x\|^2-2\langle x,y \rangle +\|y\|^2.$$ Therefore, $$\langle x,y\rangle=0.$$

Comment: Note this assumes $<x,y>=<y,x>$ so Euclidean scalar product.

Comment: @zwim yes, that was my hipotesis.

Answer (score 0):

Just square the relation and explicitly write in terms of the scalar product:
$$||x+y||^2=||x-y||^2\\(x+y)\cdot(x+y)=(x-y)\cdot(x-y)\\||x||^2+||y||^2+2x\cdot y=||x||^2+||y||^2-2x\cdot y$$
This yields $x\cdot y=0$